# overflow: hidden doesn't work in li child

Tags: html, css

I have a list in a sidebar. I want the list children to cut off, and show an ellipsis (...) when they can't fit in the sidebar.

I've added `overflow: hidden` and `text-overflow: ellipsis`, but it's not working. I think I somehow need to give the children (buttons in this case) some kind of dimensions, but I'm not sure how to do that in this case

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 700px;
  display: flex;
}

#sidebar {
  min-width: 200px;
  background: #bada55;
  z-index: 10;
}

#content {
  min-width: 300px;
  background: lightblue;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

li::before {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: -4px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  content: '';
}

button {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="sidebar">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <button>
          Button 1 Button 1 Button 1
        </button>
      </li>
      <li>
        List item with nested ul and a long text
        <ul>
          <li>
            <button>
              Nested 1
            </button>
          </li>
          <li>
            <button>
              Nested 2
            </button>
          </li>
          <li>
            <button>
              Nested 3 Has Really Long Text That Should Force Ellipsis
            </button>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <button>
          Button 3
        </button>
      </li>
      <li>
        <button>
          Button 4
        </button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas ultrices sem ac euismod rutrum. Mauris gravida pellentesque eleifend. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Proin cursus, odio ut molestie commodo, eros dolor dignissim ante, id dapibus est turpis non enim. Donec eget congue lorem. Praesent consequat magna ac sollicitudin pulvinar. Mauris varius sem dui, at convallis augue tempus eget.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a jsfiddle as well https://jsfiddle.net/h5fm7cdp/2/

How do I get the text in the buttons to be cut off, and show ... instead of overflowing into the main content?

Comment: max-width:100% .. (always a width constraint with overflow)

Comment: @TemaniAfif I'm sure that's part of the answer, but it doesn't seem to be enough

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that you need to set `max-width` of `button` and `white-space` of `li`:

```
li {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

button {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

An example can be seen here:

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 700px;
  display: flex;
}

#sidebar {
  min-width: 200px;
  background: #bada55;
  z-index: 10;
}

#content {
  min-width: 300px;
  background: lightblue;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li::before {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: -4px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  content: '';
}
button {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="sidebar">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <button>
            Button 1 Button 1 Button 1
          </button>
        </li>
        <li>
          List item with nested ul and a long text111
          <ul>
            <li>
              <button>
                Nested 1
              </button>
            </li>
            <li>
              <button>
                Nested 2
              </button>
            </li>
            <li>
              <button>
                Nested 3 Has Really Long Text That Should Force Ellipsis
              </button>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button>
            Button 3
          </button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button>
            Button 4
          </button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas ultrices sem ac euismod rutrum. Mauris gravida pellentesque eleifend. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Proin cursus, odio ut molestie commodo, eros dolor dignissim ante, id dapibus est turpis non enim. Donec eget congue lorem. Praesent consequat magna ac sollicitudin pulvinar. Mauris varius sem dui, at convallis augue tempus eget.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Close, but I don't want the buttons to wrap to a new line, that's why I had `nowrap` set. And if possible, I'd want the text that's not in a button to also cut off with an ellipsis if it can't fit.

Comment: @Tobbe ooops, I see you've found an answer:)

Answer (score 1):

With this CSS it seems to work!

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 700px;
  display: flex;
}

#sidebar {
  min-width: 200px;
  background: #bada55;
  z-index: 10;
}

#content {
  min-width: 300px;
  background: lightblue;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

li::before {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -4px;
  left: 0;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  content: '';
}
button {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Thanks for your input @TemaniAfif and @StepUp